# Search Kit results contain html code instead of plain text or formatted html

Tags: searchkit, ckeditor, html

With search kit, I create a search which finds me details of acitivities.
When e perform the search, the text of the field "details" of each activity selected is displayed. Unfortunately, it shows the html tags that where entered (with CKEditor 4, which is enabled in settings) instead of either showing formatted html or plain text ignoring the tags.
When I disable the CKEditor 4 for entering values, the problem is solved from then on. Older entries will still show html.
I need the CKEditor in other fields, not this one, but it seems it can only be disabled or enabled for al fields.
Does anyone know a solution to this:
Having CKEditor enabled, thus entering html in a field (activity) but still get a reasonable output from that field with search kit?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you on? I thought this issue was fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not providing that info in the first place. It is actually an outdated issue (5.52) so that may very well be the reason.